# xampp control panel error about administrative rights

Tags: php, xampp

My xampp control panel is display a message saying:

> You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for most
>   application stuff but whenever you do something with services there
>   will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think  about
>   running this application with administrator rights!

what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can run xamp by right click and run as administrator or you can use services in windows OS to start and stop each service just like [this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2495-services-start-disable.html)